# I published my ASP.NET Core app to a local IIS server but it's not up to date. What happened?

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

It's showing an old version of the app that I'd previously published, and it's failing to connect to the database. I didn't get any errors when publishing. The files such as site.css are up to date on the filesystem but they're not appearing in my browser properly, and the database connection is broken. I tried clearing my cache, deleting the old files, and restarting the app pool to no avail. What happened? How can I get the latest version of my app running under IIS?

Comment: I think the most obvious thing to check is the IIS physical path is correct.  I assume you have done that.  Perhaps remove the IIS site and redefine to determine if you can identify the root cause.

Comment: “I didn't get any errors when publishing.” But how did you publish?

Comment: The IIS physical path is c:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyAppName; the files are being copied there correctly. I published from Visual Studio using the Build > Publish menu option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out with some help from a Discord chat: The site looked old because my CSS was minified and the minified CSS had not been re-minified after I last modified it.

Comment: that's why i only minifiy my js and css after am done developing and testing

Answer (score 2):

What I normally try & do to troubleshoot issues like this is to break everything down into smaller pieces to see if I can work out exactly where the issue is.. For this situation I would of done something like:

1. Upload a basic test.html file that I can call from the browser to ensure that I am actually uploading everything to the correct site (don't ask how many times I have got this wrong..lol).
2. Change some HTML code & see if the changes reflect on the new published site?
3. Change some CSS code & see if the changes reflect on the new published site?
4. Change some C# code & see if the changes reflect on the new published site?
5. Change some database entries & see if the changes reflect on the new published site?

In this case I would of picked up at step 3 that the site was using an old css file as it did not pick up my latest changes.

Glad to hear you got is sorted in the end though :)